# READYAPI - Run multiple data per iteration on datasource

Tags: soapui, datasource, ready-api

I tried to use this feature: Datasource -> Rows Per Iteration, I thought the tool will process 5 data per iteration, but instead, every 5th data on the Datasource got processed. Can anyone help me on this one? I got stuck here and cant find any materials online available. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SmartBear site explains this clearly.  If you define 5 rows per iteration, you get 5 rows, but you have to access each of the five by an index.  If you don't specify the index, you get the last of the five, which is what I think you're seeing.

E.g.

```
${DataSource#Country::0}  // Index specified
${DataSource#Country}  // Index not specified.
```

Here is the link to SmartBear's site.  [Link](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/data-source.html?sbsearch=DataSource#getrow)